# Add .click() to each item in a array

Tags: javascript, html, bookmarklet

I'm trying to `.click()` all items in an array, how can I do this?
JQuery cant be used.

```
var information = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-list-element menu-list-element-basic clickable with-icon-left with-icon-right ");

for (i = 10; i < information.length; i++) {
    //.click() all items in the information array
}
```

Comment: What did you try? Also, `var information` is not an Array. It behaves like one though.

Comment: @putvande ive not tried anything yet im completely lost as with how i can do this

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("class");

for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
  elements[i].click();
}
```

Working [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/x3hdaf1d/).

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);

function myFunction() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("example");

  for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    elements[i].click();
  }
}
```

```css
.example {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="example">
<input type="checkbox" class="example">
<input type="checkbox" class="example">
<input type="checkbox" class="example">
<input type="checkbox" class="example">

<button id="btn">
  Simulate click
</button>
```

**P.S.** [`.click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) (as you ask) is not the [`click event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) but a javascript function that simulates the click event, from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click):

> The HTMLElement.click() method simulates a mouse-click on an element.

**If you want to use `click` as event:**

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("example");

  for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    elements [i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        /* Do your stuffs here */
    });
  }
```

---

**Or with Jquery:**

Use jquery [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) instead:

```
$(".class").each(function(){
  $(this).click();
  /* Or for the event */
  $(this).click(function() {
    /* Do your stuffs here */
  });
});
```

Comment: Nice answer but i cant use Jquery in this instance

Comment: I've complete my answer

Comment: what do you mean by ```/* Do your stuffs here */``` All we want to do is click on the elements, right? Nothing more?

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
var information = document.getElementsByClassName("...");
var info_items = Array.from(information.children); // Extracts all the child elements and transforms them into an Array

info_items.forEach(item => {
   $(item).click(function() {
      /* 
         Your code for when each item is clicked 
         You can also access data for each item using event.target
      */
   });
});
```

`event.target` is a resource from jQuery you can use to access data from the event's target. You can get data like id, className, nodeName, etc.

Comment: information.children throwing error.
It should be
var info_items = Array.from(information); // Extracts all the child elements and transforms them into an Array

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySeletorAll`

```
var elementList = document.querySelectorAll('.class');
```

It returns a list, so you have to loop through each element in the list and add the event handler:

```
for (var i = 0; i < elementList.length; i++) {
    elementList[i].addEventListener(".click", function() {
        // handle click
    });
}
```